# i want to round up values like 124.33 to 124.50 and 124.57 to 125.00 in C#

Tags: c#, windows, winforms, rounding

if doublevalue = 124.75 then it shoud be rounded to 125.00
if doublevalue = 124.25 then it shoud be rounded to 124.50

in short after decimal point digit greater than 50 must rounded to 100 and less than 50 should rounded to 50

please help me get this type of code

Comment: what youve got ?

Comment: And where are you stuck with your current code as you forgot to include that. Among [these](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+decimal+rounding) one should get you started

Comment: double result = Convert.ToDouble(Math.Ceiling(doublevalue/0.5)*0.5);

Comment: IMO, this question doesn't deserve to be closed as "too broad".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply do the following:

```
Math.Ceiling(YourValue * 2)/2
```

### Explanation

Suppose your number can be written as `X + Y`, where X is the integer part and Y is the fractional part. Multiplying it with 2 will make it `2X + 2Y`, where `2X` will be an even number, double of the integer part. For `Y`, there are two cases:

- If `Y >= 0.5`, `2Y` will be equal to `1 + Z` (where `0 <= Z < 1`), thus the entire number will be `2X + 1 + Z`.
- If `Y < 0.5`, `2Y` will be equal to `Z` (where `0 <= Z < 1`), thus the entire number will be `2X + Z`.

Doing `Math.Ceiling()` in the first case will return `2X + 2` and dividing it by `2` will return `X + 1`, which is the nearest higher integer, (3.7 will become 4).

Doing `Math.Ceiling()` in the second case will return `2X + 1` and dividing it by `2` will return `X + 0.5`, or `X.5` , (3.3 will become 3.5).

Comment: Why not explain why that works? Would make your answer more informative.

Comment: @AndrewTruckle: Thanks for the heads up, added explanation.

Comment: thanks @dotNET it works properly :)

Answer (score 0):

your conditions are not clear from your question, but the principle is to isolate the digits after the decimal point and that decide what to do:

```
private static double GetFixedNumber(double n)
{
    var x = n - Math.Floor(n);
    double result = 0;

    if (x >= 0.75)
    {
        result = Math.Floor(n) + 1;
    }
    else if (x >= 0.25)
    {
        result = Math.Floor(n) + 0.5;
    }
    else
    {
        result = Math.Floor(n);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Or compute it yourself:

```
    // flipped the decision around - else it is kindof the same.
    static double WorksAsWell(double input)
    {
        var floored = Math.Floor(input);

        if (floored == input) // special case so exact 127. stays that way
            return floored;

        if (input - floored >= 0.5)
            return floored+1;

        return floored+0.5;
    }

    static double RoundToHalfesOrFulls(double input)
    {
        int asInt = (int)Math.Floor(input);
        double remainder = input-asInt;

        if(remainder < 0.5)
            return asInt+0.5;

        return asInt+1.0;
    } 

    public static void Main()
    {
        for(int i= 12700; i < 12800; i+=5)
            System.Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} = {1}",i/100.0, RoundToHalfesOrFulls(i/100.0)));
    }
}
```

Output: (RoundToHalfesOrFulls)

```
127 = 127
127.05 = 127
127.1 = 127
127.15 = 127
127.2 = 127
127.25 = 127
127.3 = 127
127.35 = 127
127.4 = 127
127.45 = 127
127.5 = 127.5
127.55 = 127.5
127.6 = 127.5
127.65 = 127.5
127.7 = 127.5
127.75 = 127.5
127.8 = 127.5
127.85 = 127.5
127.9 = 127.5
127.95 = 127.5
```

Comment: *In short after decimal point digit greater than 50 must rounded to 100 and less than 50 should rounded to 50* that is not what your code does.

Comment: @rene thanks, must have misinterpreted smth - corrected it

Answer (score 0):

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //Your code goes here
            Console.WriteLine( RoundUp(124.25, 2));
        }
        public static double RoundUp(double input, int places)
{
    double multiplier = input*2;
         double numberround  = Math.Round(multiplier, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)/2;

     return numberround;
}
    }
}
```